# How to beat Night 5 in FNAF 1?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys

I've tried for a long time, but in the game, everyone's aggression levels are incredibly high. and I barely survived night 4 when everyone's aggression was lower, now you have to check Foxy every 5 seconds, Bonnie moves at random and Freddy is just impossible, I simply don't have the time to keep the camera on him while focusing on Foxy AND check the doors. Bonnie moves so fast and randomly on night 5 that my left door is closed pretty much 60% of the time, Chica is more manageable as she has a set path but still moves almost as soon as the night begins. I try to save power by only closing the doors if my lights show them, I never check 2a, 2b, 4a, 4b anymore, but I still run out of power by 4 AM. the best I've ever done is having Freddy's jingle last until 5 AM. any tips on how to win?